# Is this the correct way to return an empty generic value?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

I have a HashTable and I need some way to return a `not_found` result.

```
type
  TCell<T> = record
  .....
    property key: cardinal read FKey write FKey;
    property data: T read FData write FData;
  end;

  THashTable<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
  private
    FCells: array of TCell<T>;
    FEmpty: T;
  ...
    constructor Create(InitialSize: cardinal); overload;
    function Lookup(key: cardinal): T;
  ...
  end;

constructor THashTable<T>.Create(InitialSize: cardinal);
begin
  inherited Create;
  // Initialize regular cells
  FArraySize:= InitialSize;
  Assert((FArraySize and (FArraySize - 1)) = 0); // Must be a power of 2
  SetLength(FCells, FArraySize);

  FillChar(FEmpty, SizeOf(FEmpty), #0);  //Superfluous I know, just there to
                                         //demonstrate the point. 
end;
```

Given the above structure, how do I return a `not found` result?
If I had pointers, I would return a `nil` pointer to `T`.
But pointers to generic types are not allowed.

So I've come up with the solution below:

```
function THashTable<T>.Lookup(key: cardinal): T;
var
  Cell: NativeUInt;
begin
  if (key <> 0) then begin
    // Check regular cells
    Cell:= First_Cell(IntegerHash(key));
    while (true) do begin
      if (FCells[Cell].key = key) then Exit(FCells[Cell].data);
      if not (FCells[Cell].key = 0) then Exit(FEmpty);  <<-- is this correct?
      Cell:= Circular_Next(Cell);
    end;
  end else begin
    Result:= FEmpty;   <<--- Can I return an empty generic like this?
  end;
end;
```

**Can I return a zero-initialized generic to mean `no result`?**

Or will I run into problems with structured types of  (classes/records/variants/strings etc).

Note that I do understand the ambiguity when `T` is an integer. Zero might very well be a valid value and it would thus be indistinguishable from not_found.
I'm not worried about those results.

Comment: you can use something like this :    Result := T(nil);

Comment: @David : In fact delphi Object are pointer => Sizeof(Object)=SizeOf(Pointer), so casting to nil is correct .

Comment: @S.MAHDI, where do you get the idea that `T` has to be an Object? It can be anything.

Comment: @Johan I know that     T   can be anything , my goal is to proof that casting to nil is corret.  Inside Class delphi treats any variable that had a size greater than SizeOf(Pointer) as a Pointer .

Comment: @David : There is a misunderstanding here .. , inside class, when passing variables into functions, delphi will treats variables that had size greater than PointerSize as a Pointer => so when passing this variables you are just passing them as pointer (It is similar to string types).. for more information see register calling convertion (how it's works ?).

Comment: @S.MAHDI, can you make that discussion a separate question please? And can you guys get off my lawn now? The comments are getting longer than the question.

Comment: @David:>Parameter passing does not depend on that .. really ????  .And before you judge that my code does not compile , why you don't test it first (Take T as integer,Object,Record,..)?

Comment: @David : Fine , believe what you want .

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I rather liked the Nullable suggestion as well...

Comment: @David : My previous code was tested on DXE4 .

Comment: @S.MAHDI Well, your code does indeed compile and work. But there's no documentation for why it does. It's nothing to do with pointer sizes and parameter passing. From what I can tell `T(nil)` is a special syntax in a generic context that results in identical code to `Default(T)` when used as an assignment rhs. Take a look at the code generated. It's clearly a special because `T(P)` does not compile where `P` is a pointer. It's a compiler special for the `nil` literal.

Comment: @S.MAHDI So, what I did not remember to say in that comment above is, sorry.

Comment: @David : The `T(nil)` works like the same way that `Default(T)` works . check this picture : [DefaultT](http://oi39.tinypic.com/16a7gvq.jpg) and  [NillT](http://oi39.tinypic.com/10f6jax.jpg) : the compiler generate the same op code for both `T(nil)` and `Default(T)` .

Comment: @S.MAHDI Yes. That's my conclusion too, hence my answer. It's a compiler special. I was a bit led off course by some of your earlier comments. But the code you gave does appear to do the same as default(T)

Comment: See also [`Interfaces with Generics - Setting to NIL`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/907406/576719).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is `default(T)`, which will return a zero value for any type T.

Comment: It's so well hidden it does not even have a help page. Nice one.

Comment: And here's how to check if the return value is in fact `default(T)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782333/how-do-i-test-a-generic-type-variable-for-equality-with-defaultt-in-delphi

Comment: Gah, I completely misread the question. I thought you wanted a nullable value rather than zero initialization. And yes, some documentation for Default() would be nice.

Comment: The only documentation I found for `Default()` is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Changes_in_Standard_Functions_and_Grammar

Answer (score 4):

@S.MAHDI suggested that you could write this code:

```
Result := T(nil);
```

My initial reaction was that this would not compile because the cast is clearly invalid. For example, this code does not compile:

```
var
  P: Pointer;
....
Result := T(P);
```

For that code the compiler reports: *E2089 Invalid typecast*.

But the assignment of `T(nil)` does compile. And when you look at the code generated, for all the cases I investigated, the code was identical to that generated for `Default(T)`.

So, my conclusion is that this apparently undocumented syntax `T(nil)` is treated specially by the compiler in a generic context, and is an alias for `Default(T)`.

I would be very interested to know if anyone can point to any official documentation for this feature.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest changing the function to use an output `var` parameter for the data, then you can use a `Boolean` for the `Result`, eg:

```
function THashTable<T>.Lookup(key: cardinal; var Value: T): Boolean;
var
  Cell: NativeUInt;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (key <> 0) then begin
    // Check regular cells
    Cell := First_Cell(IntegerHash(key));
    while Cell <> -1 do begin
      if (FCells[Cell].key = key) then begin
        Value := FCells[Cell].data;
        Exit(True);
      end;
      if (FCells[Cell].key <> 0) then Break;
      Cell := Circular_Next(Cell);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to return a pointer to the generic type instead.

```
type 
  //P<T> = ^T;
  P<T> = record {holding a pointer to T with some operator overloading}

  ....
  FCells: array of T <<-- holds T directly now.

function THashTable<K,T>.Lookup(const key: K): P<T>;
begin
  ....
  if found then Result:= @FCells[CorrectIndex]
  else Result:= nil;
end;
```

Comment: This may be what you choose to do, but you should accept Mason's answer which is the answer to the question you asked. Also, what you propose in your answer runs the risk of horrible errors if the client code holds on to the pointer beyond the next mutation of your container. Take care.